# Handling complex GET parameters with Slim Framework HTTP routing

Tags: php, routes, url-routing, slim

Assuming the following naive code:

```
$app->get( '(/store(/:url)+)', function( $url = NULL ) use ( $app ) 
    {
        // Execute actions on $url
    });
```

The above works fine for the following:

```
http://localhost/api/0001/store/url-data
```

But it fails for:

```
http://localhost/api/0001/store/http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2FSomething
http://localhost/api/0001/store/http://example.com/Something

// and other variations
```

I wish to pass a full encoded URI to handle on the server side. How can I manage to do that with Slim?

**Notes:**

Other types of HTTP Requests (POST, PUT) won't work for this given problem.

It can be solved on the other end by reformatting (serializing) the URI, but I wish this to be my last resort.

**Important Edit - Answer**

So it turns out the above is a bug in the framework which is currently being tested and hopefully fixed and released soon. I solved the problem temporarily by serializing the URI before it reaches the server side.

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own questions and accept your own answer ^_^

Comment: Passing an url as segment of a restful url isn't the best solution... I suggest you to use a get parameter instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the above is a bug in the framework which is currently being tested and hopefully fixed and released soon. I solved the problem temporarily by serializing the URI before it reaches the server side.